# Removing Threads from memory in ThreadpoolExecutor Python

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I’m trying a list execution of program, but as one program finishes the execution, the  threadpool  starts count from the last thread number. I’m suspecting that older threads are not getting removed from the memory. If yes, then what is the way to achieve the same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and adding a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?  That way, we can see what's going on.

Comment: If you really do mean "threads" and not "tasks," then that is expected behavior from a thread pool. The whole point of a thread pool is that it keeps its worker threads alive so that they can be used again and again. A sophisticated thread pool might kill off threads that have been idle for some period of time, but the [documentation for `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) doesn't seem to talk about that.

Comment: If your program has no further need of a ThreadPoolExecutor that it created, then maybe you should shut it down.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.